# Select > Option > Post value issue

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass data with an Select Option instead of requiring the user to type it manually. However, I cannot get it to pass the value. I have a error message for missing values that is a predefined msg:

`Please Enter The Issuing State for your Drivers License`.

Not sure where I am going wrong. If someone would be so kind to point me in the right direction.

PHP

```
if (empty($_POST['driverslicensestate'])) { $error[] = 'Please Enter The Issuing State for your Drivers License ';} 
    else { $driverslicensestate = $_POST['driverslicensestate']; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="elements">
        <select id="driverslicensestate" name"driverslicensestate">
            <option selected value="-1">Select Drivers License State</option>
            <option id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate" value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate"  value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate"  value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate"  value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate"  value="CA">California</option>
            <option  id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate" value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate"  value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option  id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate" value="DE">Delaware</option>
...
    </select>   
</div>
```

Using 
works just fine when using just a text field.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Drivers License #" id="driverslicense" name="driverslicense" size="25" />
```

Comment: For why add 'name' attribute to options ?!

Comment: the `id` of an element MUST be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left an equal to!

```
<select id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate">
                                     ^
```

And why do you add name attribute to options? Just value is enough I suppose!

Comment: tired, and not thinking adds to adding the name to options lol, and missing the = is need to get off the computer :) Thank you.

Comment: I couldn't get your language, has adding = solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add '=' to select

```
<select id="driverslicensestate" name="driverslicensestate">
```